# jQuery fade in container, fade out and fade in next container

Tags: jquery, actionscript, containers, fadein, fadeout

I wonder if there is any way (using jQuery) to get the same effect that page - the customer wants the same effect, but in jQuery (this is in actionscript - http://www.shoppingmetropolitanobarra.com.br/site/web/lojas.php).

I tried to turn into a jQuery code, but without success:

http://jsfiddle.net/pq667/2/

There will be several containers, each with multiple thumbnails using jQuery `animate` method, ie a container finished, should use the `fadeOut` effect and `fadeIn` the next container  (**happens when the page loads**).

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you use [jQuery instead of MooTools](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/pq667/4/) it seems to do something. But I'm not sure of what it is that you're looking for.

Comment: I'll make this for you and i'll give you a jsfiddle link. Give me ~15mins...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at my example http://jsfiddle.net/qEAJu/20/ , if you want to achieve that zooming effect consider using [this plugin](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/) for css transitions.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The effect is very similar, the big question is: How to go to the next container after the fadeOut of the preview container.

Comment: What do you mean by ,,go to the next container" ?

Comment: Is this what you are seeking for? http://jsfiddle.net/qEAJu/54/ Just call the plugin on the group of elements... I've also included scaling and switched to css transitions...

Comment: @hjuster: Very very good, the effect is PERFECT. But my main question is: There will be three containers, each one with 8 stores, how can I move to the second container after the container 1 fadeOut finish.

Answer (score 1):

I often change this snippet from http://paulirish.com/2008/sequentially-chain-your-callbacks-in-jquery-two-ways/. The self-executing callback chain on an arbitrary jQuery object *via: temp01*

```
(function hidenext(jq){
    jq.eq(0).fadeOut("fast", function(){
        (jq=jq.slice(1)).length && hidenext(jq);
    });
})($('div#bodyContent a'));
```

You could change what's above to something like this:

```
$('.block').hide();

(function showNext(ele){
    ele.eq(0).fadeIn('slow', function(){
        (ele=ele.slice(1)).length && showNext(ele);
    });
})($('.block'))​
```

Here's a jsFiddle I set up to show you the possibilities: http://jsfiddle.net/hqgVS/

Comment: The problem with that is that it won't be possible to overlap the animations like in the OP's example.

Comment: That's true. It's an elegant solution, not 100% perfect for this example, but there is potential to take what's been done, and build something a bit more bespoke to fulfill the project requirements.

Comment: @Andy — +1, your solution is really nice!

Answer (score 1):

This exact effect is only possible with CSS3 transformations.
The reason for this is the scaling of the text. You can of course fake it by changing the size of the element and even the font, but it'll be very hard to achieve the desired effect.

For example:

**jQuery:**

```
$('li').each(function(i, el) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(el).addClass('show');
    }, ($('li').length - i) * 500);
});​
```

**CSS:**

```
li.show{
   -webkit-transition:all 1s ease-out;
   opacity:1;
   -webkit-transform:scale(1);   
}
```

**Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/6xL7R/
(view on webkit browser like Chrome, since i omitted the other vendor prefixes)

---

You can do the opacity animation with jQuery though:

**jQuery:**

```
$('li').css({'opacity':0}).each(function(i,el){
    $(el).delay(($('li').length-i)*500).animate({'opacity':1},1000);
});
```

(the commented part in my fiddle)

Maybe a combination of the two would work out for you?
Showing the scale on compatible browsers.

Or check the browser with http://modernizr.com/

Comment: You can do the position with jQuery as well.  You just animate top & left at the same time as width & height :)

Comment: @Archer: sure, but that won't scale the contents of the element. And can result in weird behavior with text breaking. I'll update my answer to clarify.

Comment: @Andy: Very good, dude! But how can I move to the next container (which has another 8 stores)?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to play with positioning, as you'll see, but this does the fade in, delay, fade out that you asked for...

http://jsfiddle.net/pq667/11/

It was simply a case of adding another delay, after the 1st animate, and then another animate to do the opposite.

I'd recomment positioning them all absolutely, inside a relatively positioned container, and animating the position (left & top) as well as the width and height.